# I am not able to load content from a link into web view in my activity

Tags: android, webview

Following is calling activity in my adapter.

```
  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(mContext, PdfViewActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("path", curr.getContry());
            in.putExtra("name", curr.getDis());
            in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

My veb view is as below

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.webkit.WebSettings;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

   import com.shuan.Project.R;

  public class PdfViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView web;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private String path = "http://www.example.com/sample.pdf";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_view);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle("Candidate : "+getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_web);

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

    web.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" +getIntent().getStringExtra("path"));

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getIntent().getStringExtra("path"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
}
```

While i am trying to view the distinct feature in my webview am seeing like html tags and all. How can i fix? I want to load content into my webview which is saved in my database and i am fetching it by a link.Where i got mistaken?

Comment: link the output being displayed...

Comment: output means ? in web view I am seeing the html codes alone .I have both android applcation and website.